# Change the date order of a txt file

Tags: bash, powershell, shell

I have a variable where I dump the day, month and year of some events.

$Myvariable ->
`17/10/2022`

I need to change the order of the day and month.

$NewVariable->
`10/17/2022`

Would someone know how to do it? Any ideas?

I'm starting to work with powershell and I can't think of a way to do it.Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: Please only use the  [tag:powershell] tag, not also the [tag:bash] tag, if you're only looking for a PowerShell solution. It's best to focus questions on _one_ language.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell

```ps
$NewVariable = '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}' -f [datetime]::ParseExact($MyVariable, 'dd/MM/yyyy',$null)
```

<sup>If your current Regional Settings dictate hyphens instead of slashes in the output format (like on my machine which has Dutch settings), you might want to change `'{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'` into `'{0:MM\/dd\/yyyy}'`.
By prefixing the slashes with backslashes, you will effectively escape them so the output is always like `10/17/2022`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74267512/45375):

A solution based on *text manipulation*, using the [`-split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) and [`-join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operators, combined with [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) indexing:

```
$MyVariable = '17/10/2022'

# -> '10/17/2022'
$NewVariable =
  ($MyVariable -split '/')[1, 0, 2] -join '/'
```

---

A solution based on [`[datetime]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) objects, as in Theo's answer:

```
$MyVariable = '17/10/2022'

# -> '10/17/2022'
$NewVariable =
  [datetime]::Parse($MyVariable, [cultureinfo] 'en-GB').ToString('MM"/"dd"/"yyyy')
```

Working with `[datetime]` objects gives you much more flexibility, if needed:

- The solution takes advantage of the fact that `17/10/2022`, i.e. a day-first date format with `/` separators, is used in the `en-GB` (UK-English) culture, and therefore can be parsed as-is in the context of that culture. The resulting `[datetime]` instance is then formatted as needed, using the `.ToString()` method.
- If your current culture is the US-English culture, you can simplify to `.ToString('d')`, because `10/17/2022` is that culture's short date format (`d`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash answer:

```
Myvariable='17/10/2022'

# EDIT:  Using Cyrus's FS,OFS improvement:
Newvariable=$( awk  'BEGIN { FS=OFS="/" }{ print $2,$1,$3 }' <<< "$Myvariable" )

echo $Newvariable
```

Results:

```
10/17/2022
```

Comment: An alternative with input and output field separator: `awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/" }{ print $2,$1,$3 }' <<< "$Myvariable"`